# Calculating Kp in two different ways

Tags: equilibrium

> The degree of dissociation of $\ce{NH3}$ at $\pu{1 atm}$ is 20 % as follows:
>      $$\ce{2NH3 <=> N2 + 3H2} $$

I follow two ways but end up with two different answers.

Here, I assume that initial amount of reactant mole is 2 and that of product is 0. Then I take the amount of ammonia in equilibrium to be $2-2\alpha$, nitrogen to be $\alpha$ and hydrogen to be $3\alpha$. Then, I find $K_\mathrm{p}$ (where $\alpha=0.2$).

Here, as dissociation is 20 %, I assume that amount of ammonia in equilibrium will be 0.8 and that of nitrogen and hydrogen will be 0.2 and 0.6 respectively. Then also, I find $K_\mathrm{p}$, but it differs from the initial one.

Where am I mistaken?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First solution is perfect.

The issue is in the second solution.

If we start with 1 mole of $\ce{NH3}$ then with 20% dissociation we are left with 0.8 moles as 0.2 moles react these 0.2 moles give o.1 mole of $\ce{N2}$ and 0.3 moles of $\ce{H2}$

Hence $$K_\mathrm p = \frac{[\ce{H2}]^3[\ce{N2}]}{[\ce{NH3}]^2} = \frac{[\ce{0.3}]^3[\ce{0.1}]}{[\ce{0.8}]^2}$$

Comment: That means for $2 mol$ , I should say $1.6 mol$ $NH_{3}$ remains in equilibrium ...?

Comment: @NehalSamee yes that is perfectly correct

Comment: ...But, if we take that total mole at equilibrium be 100 , then equilibrium contains 80 mol $NH_{3}$ , 15 mol $H_2$ and 5 mol $N_2$ ...Then , the calculation doesn't match ...

Comment: that is not the definition of degree of dissociation degree of dissociation is % of reactant that undergoes reaction @NehalSamee

Comment: But I'm not finding any way of mistake in my argument nor in yours ...@KarmanyaGB

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociation_(chemistry)#Dissociation_degree read this try to apply here. @NehalSamee

Comment: @NehalSamee Karmanya's answer is right. If you lose 0.2 moles of the reactant, you get only 0.1 moles of dinitrogen.

Comment: @GaurangTandon ... OK ...Then , if I say that 20% of product remains in equilibrium , then will my argument be applicable ?

Comment: What say @KarmanyaGB .

Comment: There are two products. 20% of which one?

Comment: @NehalSamee lets start from scratch. what according to you is degree of dissociation?

Comment: @GaurangTandon ... I said , like if only 80% reactant remains at equilibrium ...

Comment: Then , mole fraction is $0.8$

Comment: @NehalSamee correct if 80% remains how much reacted?

Comment: The question does not state that 2 mol reactant is given ...

Comment: take it as X. solution is still same

Comment: Then , amount of $N_2$ is $\frac{1}{4}×20% $ ...